# Charts for iOS, hide the map from chart

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

How can I hide the chart map as described in the picture? Couldn’t find it anywhere in the documentation..

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: are you using Charts . ? https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase you are using the Charts pod by danielgindi ([Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts) / [GitHub](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)):

**Charts Version 3.0**:

```
chartView.legend.enabled = false
```

This will hide the chart legend (or *chart map* how you called it).